# Approximation of any reversible process by carnot cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, carnot-cycle

While studying thermodynamics i came across the fact that any reversible cycle can be represented by series of miniature carnot cycles. I am unable to understand how can it be done for every cycle as carnot cycle has 4 reversible processes that may or may not be part of the reversible process that we want to represent. And i also unable to understand how geometrically can it be fitted to any reversible process. Please help in this.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figure 7.1 answers the question but the $PV$ graph makes it hard to understand the answer. It easier to represent the process on the $TS$ graph because the Carnot cycle on this graph is rectangle.
[image]

Using tiny rectangles we can reproduce the area of any closed line on the $TS$ graph. All tiles move in the same direction (here clockwise), so wherever two tiles share a side they cancel each other out. The net circulation is on the edge and it can be made to match any arbitrary cycle.

The $PV$ graph works the same way but the tiles are not rectangles but rather these toothy slices.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Themis , i understood.